# Deducting Federal Income Tax from State Income Tax Liability

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax

Context: I am calculating what my taxes will be next year (2021) for purposes of filling out my W-4s such that my withholdings will be as close to my actual tax liability as possible, to minimize my tax refund.  I live in Oregon.

I am going to be itemizing deductions for the tax year of 2021, rather than taking the standard deduction.  This means that I can deduct my Oregon income tax (OIT) from my federal income tax (FIT) liability.  However, in a handful of states, including my state of Oregon, I can also do the reverse: I can deduct my *FIT* from my *OIT* liability... which will then in turn re-affect my FIT liability, which will again re-affect my OIT liability... in other words, it creates a seemingly circular dependency.

My question is:  *What is the correct way to resolve this?*  Or, more specifically, *Is the way I resolved it, the correct way?*

My solution was to first calculate my OIT liability *without deducting FIT*, and then calculate my FIT liability including the deduction of my OIT, to get my initial calculated amounts.  These were approximately an OIT of $4400 and an FIT of $5000.  I then recalculated my OIT by deducting my FIT, and then adjusted my FIT wit the new OIT, and rinse and repeat until I reached a stable amount for each tax liability where the result of adjusting the one no longer changed the amount of the other.  The end result was an OIT around $3900 and an FIT around $5100 (in other words, about $400 total less than owed tax than when I started).

So my question is, *is this the right way to resolve this circular dependency, via recursion?*

Answer (score 2):

The federal deduction for state taxes is not determined by your state tax liability, but by the taxes you actually paid (or had withheld from your paychecks) during the calendar year, so the payment you will make to your state in early 2021 for the 2020 tax year will be deducted on your 2021 federal taxes, not your 2020 federal taxes.

Your federal tax liability for 2020 won't be changed by what you pay to the State of Oregon, provided you wait until after Jan 1 to pay any taxes due to Oregon.

Comment: That's just it though, I'm NOT waiting until Jan 1 of 2021 to pay my 2020 Oregon taxes (nor am I waiting until 2022 to pay my 2021 Oregon taxes).  My 2020 Oregon taxes are being withheld in 2020, and my 2021 Oregon taxes will be withheld in 2021.  The context of my question is for filling out my W-4s for my taxes in 2021, with the goal of getting my 2021 withholdings for both state and federal as close as possible to my actual 2021 tax liability.  So I think the circular dependency is still a factor, and I don't think this really answers my question.

Comment: @JamesDunn, but are you filing your federal taxes before Dec 31, or can you wait and file between Jan 1 and Apr 15?

Comment: @JamesDunn, Your withholding isn't expected to be perfectly accurate. Just fill it in "close enough" and pay the difference or get a refund when you file like everyone else.

Comment: Sure, I'm not worried about getting it "wrong" since it's only a few hundred dollars, and I'm happy to follow that advice; but I am nonetheless still curious as to exactly what is considered "correct" when the actual amounts are calculated.

Comment: Or make sure you make enough money that your federal tax liability is more than $6800, which maxes out the Oregon deduction, and then small changes in your federal taxes won't affect your Oregon liability.

Comment: What's correct for your federal taxes is to use the amounts actually paid to your state during the calendar year. I don't know for the state of Oregon whether it's based on actual payments or on the liability for the tax year.

Comment: "make sure you make enough money that your federal tax liability is more than $6800"... well, yes, hee hee.  That would make it simpler.  Not sure I'll get there though, I'm hoping to have a lot of kids, so credits/exemptions will probably keep my liability low.

Comment: "What's correct for your federal taxes is to use the amounts actually paid to your state during the calendar year."  Does that mean that if I way overpaid with high withholdings for my state taxes in 2021, that I wouldn't have to adjust the amount down when I filed and receive a large state refund in 2022?  That doesn't seem right, but if it is, then I'll TOTALLY go for high withholdings.

Comment: Yes, but your refund check from the state will be federally taxable in the year that you receive it.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess that makes sense.  I think that means that if I go ahead with the recursive solution I mentioned in my question, it will be pretty close to my actual liability.  We'll see how my theory holds up in 2022 when I use Turbotax to file.  :P

Comment: @JamesDunn Don't homebrew your own solution; use the method prescribed by the tax authorities. For Federal taxes, that means deduct the actual taxes paid to your state between 2020-01-01 and 2020-12-31, irrespective of what your actual tax liability was, then declare your state refund, if any, as taxable income the following year. If you do otherwise, then you are entering false information on your tax return.

Comment: @Nobody, thanks, but this question is not about filing my tax return for 2020.  It's about filling out my W-4 for withholdings for 2021.  Two very different things.  I use Turbotax when I actually file my taxes.

Comment: @JamesDunn Actually, the same thing applies (and you're overthinking this). There's no infinite recursion to worry about because neither OR no the Feds are paying you refunds or collecting taxes from you instantaneously. So, you only need to account for income or tax in the year that you actually get that income or pay that tax. So, assuming that you will get an OR refund for tax year 2020 for 2021, base your W4 for 2021 on the fact that as far as your tax returns are concerned for 2020, your federal income will be job income + 2019 OR refund (assuming you've gotten it) [1 of 2]

Comment: @JamesDunn - 2020 OR taxes (that you have already paid) and whatever other credits/deductions. I say you're overthinking because it seems you expect that you can converge on a single exact answer. You can't. That's because your taxes depend on the year in which you get the income or tax liability. Let's say that for some reason, OR takes until 2022 to pay your refund for 2020. Then your OR refund will be federal taxable income in 2022, not 2021. That immediately breaks the recursion as you don't know now what the tax rates will be in 2022 for either your federal or state taxes. [2 of 2]